# R markdown error "object '...' not found", with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

Below is part of the .rmd file content.

````
## Loading and preprocessing the data

Load the data with dplyr and data.table package into a data table called activity.
```{Load, echo=TRUE}
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
activity<-fread("activity.csv")
```

The date has character type. Use lubridate to produce a POSIX typed date for further processing.
```{Change date, echo=T}
library(lubridate)
activity<-mutate(activity,POSIXdate=activity[,date])
```

## What is mean total number of steps taken per day?

Use summarize function in dyplyr package to sum up steps variable, with activity grouped by dates, and store it into a new data table called stepsPerDay.
```{Sum each day, echo=TRUE}
stepsPerDay<-summarize(group_by(activity,date),steps=sum(steps,na.rm=T))
```

Data table stepsPerDay looks like this:
```{r, echo=F}
head(stepsPerDay)
```
````

Everything runs fine until the last line, when it gave me the error

> `object 'stepsPerDay' not found
>   Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> head
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In get_engine(options$engine) :
>     Unknown language engine 'Load' (must be registered via knit_engines$set()).
>   2: In get_engine(options$engine) :
>     Unknown language engine 'Change' (must be registered via knit_engines$set()).
>   3: In get_engine(options$engine) :
>     Unknown language engine 'Sum' (must be registered via knit_engines$set()).
>   Execution halted`

I have tried

```
head(stepsPerDay)
```

or

```
summary(stepsPerDay)
```

or

```
StepsPerDay
```

All return the same error.
I believe the object is generated in markdown file, so it should be there. I have no idea why the object is not found.
Thank you for helping!

Comment: the paradigm is `\`\`\`{r chunk_label, options}`

Comment: @rawr You are right, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @rawr mentioned, I forgot to put "r" in the bracket.